# Does scala specification 2.10 and 2.11 exist?

Tags: scala, specifications

I have visited scala [official site](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/198.html) so there is only one link to [pdf specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/sites/default/files/linuxsoft_archives/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf). And this specification about scala 2.9. Is there documents for 2.10 and 2.11 scala versions? I mean full pdf's for each version?

Comment: Just so others viewing this are not confused, this question is not about the normal user-oriented documentation, which is certainly available for 2.10 and 2.11.  The question is about the more rigorous *language specification*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<strike>No.</strike> (October 2014, that starts to change: **[Scala 2.11 spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/)**)

Original answer (August 2014)

It is in the work though, [as mentioned last February](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/scala-user/specification/scala-user/VqVFjcKeiJ8/_fsIJp3WUjwJ), just not "as pdf":

> We are working on an updated spec, hopefully in markdown format so that contributions are made simpler.
>   A spec is IMO an essential thing and at the same time I realize it's not nearly in the state I would like it to be.
>   I do have a lot of hope that sometimes in the near future we can reach a point where the spec is more complete and it and the compiler are pretty much in agreement. But it will take work and time to get there.
>
> - Martin

(Martin = [Martin Odersky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Odersky), who designed the Scala programming language)

---

[Jörg W Mittag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2988/j%C3%B6rg-w-mittag) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25321482/does-scala-specification-2-10-and-2-11-exist/25321598#comment39476390_25321598):

> Note however that some **larger language changes have [SIPs](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/sip-list.html)** (Scala Improvement Process), which include a somewhat-formal specification. E.g.

- [SIP-13: Implicit Classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/completed/implicit-classes.html),
- [SIP-15: Value Classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/completed/value-classes.html),
- [SIP-18: Modularizing Language Features](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/completed/modularizing-language-features.html).

As mentioned in [Langley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/180742/langley)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26258652/6309), [Scala 2.11 has an html spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/).

Comment: Note however that some larger language changes have SIPs, which include a somewhat-formal specification. E.g. [SIP-13: Implicit Classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/completed/implicit-classes.html), [SIP-15: Value Classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/completed/value-classes.html), [SIP-18: Modularizing Language Features](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/completed/modularizing-language-features.html).

Comment: @JörgWMittag good point. I have included it in the answer for mroe visibility.

Comment: I don't see string interplators in the SLS

Answer (score 1):

There is currently (10/8/2014) a spec for 2.11 in html form here: http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/

Comment: Great to know that a spec is available. I have referenced it in my answer as well. +1

Answer (score 0):

Offline documentation can be obtained like this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install httrack -y
$ hash -r
$ mkdir $HOME/Downloads/sls_2.11
$ cd $HOME/Downloads/sls_2.11
$ httrack http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11
```